# Алгоритм распределения

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть поток клиентов и N менеджеров, у каждого из которых свой процент клиентов задан, которых он может обслужить суммарно, - у всех менеджеров не больше 100%.

То есть.
Допустим:
менеджер 1 50%
менеджер 2 25%
менеджер 3 25%

И надо равномерно (согласно процентов распределять клиентов между ними), то есть когда суммарно будет 100 клиентов у первого менеджера будет 50 клиентов и у 2-х остальных по 25.

По какому алгоритму решить эту задачу (при поступлении нового клиента определить, к какому менеджеру цеплять)?

**Обновление**

Пытался, на python как-то воспроизвести, и решить задачу, доолго и упорно гуглил. Я просто даже не представляю, куда смотреть.
http://tny.cz/eb55c611

**Обновление**

Нашел алгоритм, взевешеный рандом, Random Weighted, вот что-то подобное ищу, у меня макс 100-150 клиентов, и менеджеров до 5~, а тот алгоритм, о котором писал выше, больше подходит для небольших значений.

Comment: Ваше распределение называется не равномерное, а пропорциональное.

Comment: Нашел алгоритм, взевешеный рандом, Random Weighted, вот что-то подобное ищу, у меня макс 100-150 клиентов, и менеджеров до 5~, а тот алгоритм о которой писал выше, больше подходит для небольших значений.

Answer (score 1):

Все достаточно просто. Это обычная задача балансировки нагрузки. В каждый момент времени Вам известно, сколько сейчас клиентов и менеджеров. Посчитайте распределение задач между ними в процентах. Теперь сравните полученные проценты с заданными (просто вычтите). Полученные разницы - сортируйте. Самый верхний (или самый нижний, все зависит как разницу посчитаете) - самый менее загруженный. Вот ему задачу и можно бросать. Но это не совсем правильно. Нужно и другим набрасывать, но с меньшей вероятностью. Например, каждую вторую заявку - верхнему, каждую четвертую - второму, каждую восьмую третьему

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то эта задача напомнила мне другую: есть дом с определенным количеством этажей, на каждом этаже определенное количество квартир. Требуется определить, на каком этаже чаще всего останавливается лифт. Задачи похожи не математически, а в другом смысле. Дело в том, что при решении обеих этих задач кажется, что надо что-то хитрое использовать, вероятности там всякие, распределения гауссовы и негауссовы, взвешенные случайные числа и т.д. и т.п.

Обе задачи, на самом деле - на сообразительность, на умение представить ситуацию вживую. Даю ответ на задачу про многоэтажку: независимо ни от чего самым посещаемым этажом является первый. Ответ на задачу про менеджеров столь же прост, могу озвучить, если все еще надо...